# JSLink on managed metadata column in Sharepoint forms

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, jslink

I have a requirement in which i have to apply custom rendering to my managed metadata field. I have to convert the term store hierarchy into a group of three drop downs.

for example, I have an hierarchy of termsets like "Country" -> "State" -> "City". and the column name in the list form is "Area". Currently my form looks like this :

[image]

I want my Area field to get rendered as below from which only City value should get stored in the list.
[image]

How can I achieve this applying jslink ?
The drop down here should get filled from termstore only, i.e. the country dropdown should contain options which is there in the "Country" term set in the term store.
Means first-Dropdown = Parent/Root values
      second-Dropdown = Child values
      third-Dropdown = SubChild values

Comment: Using `JSOM` you will have to pull terms. Also instead of going `JSLink` way, have thought of making a custom new form?

Comment: Thought to but the requirements strictly states to use JSLink only